# Lighthouse Node CLI is returning wrong numbers

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

i'm trying to access the performance ratings of a website in Node js over the Lighthouse Node CLI. But i ran into this problem, where the outputted scores are way lower than the scores from Lighthouse within Chrome DevTools or Google PageSpeed.

**For example:**

In Chrome I get for https://google.com a performance score of **97** with following metrics:

- First Contentful Paint: **1.0**
- Speed Index: **1.0**
- Largest Contentful Paint: **0.99**
- Time to Interactive: **0.83**
- Total Blocking Time: **1.00**
- Cumulative Layout Shift: **0.99**

While via Node, i only get a score of **66.05** with following metrics:

- First Contentful Paint: **0.7**
- Speed Index: **0.7**
- Largest Contentful Paint: **0.65**
- Time to Interactive: **0.57**
- Total Blocking Time: **0.03**
- Cumulative Layout Shift: **1.0**

I tried it on MacOS 11.2.3 and also on Windows.

- Chrome Version: 90.0.4430.85
- Lighthouse: 7.2.0
- Axe version: 4.1.2

Runtime settings are the standard settings for both and are identical.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is my code based on this [blogpost](https://css-tricks.com/build-a-node-js-tool-to-record-and-compare-google-lighthouse-reports/):

```
const lighthouse = require("lighthouse");
const chromeLauncher = require("chrome-launcher");


const lighthouseAudit = url => {
    return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: ['--headless']}).then(chrome => {
      const opts = {port: chrome.port};
      return lighthouse(url, opts).then(results => {
        return chrome.kill().then(() => results.report);
      });
    });
  };


lighthouseAudit("https://google.com").then(resultsJSON => {
    var results = JSON.parse(resultsJSON);
    const metricFilter = [
        "first-contentful-paint",
        "interactive",
        "largest-contentful-paint",
        "speed-index",
        "cumulative-layout-shift",
        "total-blocking-time"
      ];


    let resultsScore = [];
    for (let auditObj in results["audits"]) {
      if (metricFilter.includes(auditObj)) {
          resultsScore.push(new Array(auditObj, results.audits[auditObj].score));
      }
    }
    console.log(resultsScore);

    let score = (resultsScore[0][1]*0.15)+(resultsScore[1][1]*0.15)+(resultsScore[2][1]*0.25)+(resultsScore[3][1]*0.15)+(resultsScore[4][1]*0.25)+(resultsScore[5][1]*0.05);
    console.log("Score: " + score*100);
});
```

Comment: Looking at the numbers it looks like the CPU you are using on the CLI is massively underpowered or there is something eating CPU cycles. Look at your TBT score - it goes from 100% to 3%. As TBT is basically how CPU intensive your site is it is either seeing a completely different page, parsing and executing the page in a different order (maybe it doesn't support HTTP 2 if you are using it) or the CPU is being slowed too much. A tough one to find out the cause but I am 90% sure that is where the score differences are. Try comparing the full results for both and see which audit items differ.

Comment: Thank you. I checked it again on another windows machine and the results were correct on there. Yes seems like it is a problem with the node module and the CPU...Just saw that the CPU/Memory Power-Score via node is not even the half of the score compared to DevTools. Seems like it is some kind of problem with the node module and Apple Silicon?

Comment: quite possible that it runs single threaded on Apple? That is well beyond my technical knowledge I am afraid, that is the only thing I can remotely think of!